# how to use SQL UNION in where clause having variable in query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve data from two tables using UNION but not works in my case.
I'm trying this

```
    $folq = $db->query("select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from hollywood where id = ".$parentid, database::GET_ROW) UNION ("select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from bollywood where id = ".$parentid, database::GET_ROW);
```

But not works for me. Please suggest me how to achive that.

Answer (score 1):

You need  one string query  (not two ,  and in the second  query you don't need  alias)

```
 $folq = $db->query("
  select 
      id as pid
      ,folder
      ,name as catname
      ,name
      ,thumb
      ,pathc 
  from hollywood 
  where id =  ".$parentid . 
  " UNION 
    select 
      id 
      ,folder
      ,name
      ,name
      ,thumb
      ,pathc 
  from bollywood 
  where id = ". $parentid

  , database::GET_ROW);
```

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 18

Answer (score 0):

I think have a syntax error in your query, should be like this

```
 $folq = $db->query("select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from hollywood where id = ".$parentid . " UNION select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from bollywood where id = ".$parentid, database::GET_ROW);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
        $folq = $this->db->query("
            select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from hollywood where id = $parentid 
        UNION  
            select id as pid,folder,name as catname,name,thumb,pathc from bollywood where id = ".$parentid);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works :)

```
         $folq = $db->query("
        select id as pid,folder,name as         catname,name,thumb,pathc from category where id         = $parentid 
           UNION  
            select id as pid,folder,name as         catname,name,thumb,pathc from punjabi where id         = ".$parentid, database::GET_ROW);
```